# Bxslider caption animation

Tags: javascript, html, css, slider

I am working with bxslider and I'd like to have a different animation for the slide's text.

While the slide slides to the left, I'd like the text box to be fixed in the middle and the text to fade in/out.

Any ideas? I've been trying all day

Here is a pen: [Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BPJJdO)

HTML:

```
<div class="bxslider" id="banner">
  <div>
    <img src="img" />
    <h3 class="msl-title"><a href="#" title="Test Article">Test Article</a></h3>
  </div>

  <div>
    <img src="img" />
    <h3 class="msl-title"><a href="#" title="Test Article">Test Article</a></h3>
  </div>

  <div>
    <img src="img" />
    <h3 class="msl-title"><a href="#" title="Test Article">Test Article</a></h3>
  </div>

</div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.bxslider').bxSlider();
});
```

CSS:

```
#banner .msl-title {
    width: 80%;
    max-width: 350px;
    top: 50%;
    background: white;
    padding: 40px;
    position: relative;
    margin: auto;
    overflow: auto;
    display: table;
    height: 160px;
    text-align: center;
    transform: translateY(-65%);
    border: 5px solid #61beb1;}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to find the solution. Simply take the info from the slider title and print it in an external div

```
var slideActive = $('.msl-item.active-slide .msl-title.active-text a').attr( "title" );
$( ".slider-title-box h3" ).text( slideActive );
```

The first line is looking for the slide title and the second line is printing it in the new div.

I gave absolute position to `.slider-title-box` so it'd fit over the slider.

Hope this helps another trying to achieve this

Answer (score 0):

in order to achieving this you need a different aproach, because the box its inside the slider, it is hard to make fixed, but if you put the textbox outside the slider wrapper you can simply control the behaviour with the custom bxslider

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.msl-title').find('a').text( 
   $('#banner').children().first('div').data('text') );
      $('.bxslider').bxSlider({'onSlideBefore':function(el,oldIndex,newIndex){
      $('.msl-title').fadeOut(200,function(){
      $('.msl-title').find('a').text($(el).data('text'));  
        $(this).stop().fadeIn(200);
      });
    }});
 });
```

And using data properties from jQuery you can set the Text for every slide in the div

```
<div data-text="Slide 1">
```

Working Demo
https://codepen.io/Teobis/pen/zLpWKM

Hope this helps